# reindex and stacking dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this

```
idx,key,value
1, a, 1
1, b, hi
1, d, 2
2, a, 0.5
2, d, hello
3, b, 2
4, e, 3
4, d, -1
```

I want something like the following:

```
idx, a, b, c, d, e
1,   1, hi,nan, 2, nan
2,  0.5,nan,nan,hello, nan
3,  nan,2,nan,nan,nan
4,  nan,nan,nan,-1,3
```

Is there any panda-o-ic way of achieving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot):

```
In [237]:
df.pivot(index='idx', columns='key', values='value')

Out[237]:
key    a    b      d    e
idx                      
1      1   hi      2  NaN
2    0.5  NaN  hello  NaN
3    NaN    2    NaN  NaN
4    NaN  NaN     -1    3
```

Comment: I get this error when doing pivot: 
ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Comment: you'll have to post code to create your df and the code that produces the error in your question

Comment: lets say for idx=1, I have one more key 'b'. in that case, it fails.